# Meteor render data from embeded, nested collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've been trying to get data out of a nested collection without any luck, besides using the dot notation from the html nothing seems to work.

What I want basically is to soley fetch the data I need from a nested collection. I'm trying to build a file upload for images and audio files and then a simple way to use the files. I'm using the cfs:standard-packages and cfs:filesystem packages.

The code below shows a working example of what I don't want, eg fetching the whole file object and retrieving the data in the html. If I could use the dot notation in the mongo command somehow would be perfect. I also could settle for _each but I would prefer fetching just the data I need on each db call. As you can see I'm passing an id for the whole file object here. `Uploads.find({_id:Session.get('getpic')});` BTW, the actual file is stored in a folder on my local server.

The collection:

```
 {
    "_id" : "DXFkudDGCdvLpPALP",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "drink.png",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-04-30T07:14:56.000Z"),
        "size" : 127944,
        "type" : "image/png"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-07-11T21:53:32.526Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "uploads" : {
            "name" : "drink.png",
            "type" : "image/png",
            "size" : 127944,
            "key" : "uploads-DXFkudDGCdvLpPALP-drink.png",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-07-11T21:53:32.000Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-11T21:53:32.000Z")
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template name="renderImages">
{{#each showpic}}
    <img width="300" height="300" src="/projectuploads/{{copies.uploads.key}}"/>
{{/each}}
```

Javascript:

```
Template.renderImages.helpers({
    showpic: function() {
    return Uploads.find({_id:Session.get('getpic')});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

specify the returned fields in the `find` query like so

```
return Uploads.find({_id:Session.get('getpic')}, { fields: {'copies.uploads.key': 1} } );
```

but a word on that. here you query minimongo (on the client), which is in the browsercache so it's basically free. take care to `publish` only those fields to the client that you actually want there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry to say I still get the whole file object back. I've tried this with {{key}} left in the html and { fields: {'copies.uploads': 1} } ); and { fields: {'copies.uploads.key': 1} } ); 

And also skiped the {{#each}} and used {{showpic}} instead of {{key}} with the  { fields: {'copies.uploads.key': 1} } );

Yes this is just a working example, using publish/subscribe in the real app. Thanks. Edit: also tried .fetch() and .findOne

Comment: You have to iterate through the uploads object and that may not be possible, other from the html or via an _each in the js? Maybe it's not a good idea for performance to doing operations inside the db anyway?